# Add dynamic path to sprite

Tags: android, andengine

I have to move the sprite along the path that is drawn onTouch.For that I'm using Path and PathModifier

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        int historySize = pSceneTouchEvent.getMotionEvent().getHistorySize();
        pointX = new float[historySize];
        pointY = new float[historySize];

        for (int i = 1; i < historySize; i++) {

            pointX[i] = pSceneTouchEvent.getMotionEvent().getHistoricalX(i);
            pointY[i] = pSceneTouchEvent.getMotionEvent().getHistoricalY(i);

        }
        path = new path(pointX,pointY);
        PathModifier pathModifier = new PathModifier(2.5f, path);
        pathModifier.setRemoveWhenFinished(true);
        sprite1.clearEntityModifiers();
        sprite1.registerEntityModifier(pathModifier);

        break;
```

Its giving me error as path needs at least 2 way points.
Any idea why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this shouldn't happen, since a motion event is very often more than just one coordinate. Maybe you should test if the `historySize` is really bigger than 2. In addition you can add the sprites starting coordinates, otherwise the sprite would "jump" towards the first touch point (but that wasn't your question).

This isn't actually different – just another possibility:

```
path= new Path(historySize);
for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++) {
      float x = pSceneTouchEvent.getMotionEvent().getHistoricalX(i);
      float y = pSceneTouchEvent.getMotionEvent().getHistoricalY(i);
      path.to(x,y);
}
```

In addition I noticed you start your for-loop with `int i=1` so if your `historySize`is 2, the loop iterates only one times!

**EDIT**

**I couldn't find the problem, but I found a solution:**
Instead of using the `motionEvent history`, save the coordinates of the `toucheEvent` on the go as the `touchEvent`occurs:

```
ArrayList<Float> xCoordinates; // this is where you store all x coordinates of the touchEvents
ArrayList<Float> yCoordinates; // and here will be the y coordinates.

onSceneTouchEvent(TouchEvent sceneTouchEvent){
    switch(sceneTouchEvent.getAction()){
        case (TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN):{  
            // init the list every time a new touchDown is registered
            xCoordinates = new ArrayList<Float>();   
            yCoordinates = new ArrayList<Float>();               
            break;
        }
        case (TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE): {
            // while moving, store all touch points in the lists
            xCoordinates.add(sceneTouchEvent.getX());  
            yCoordinates.add(sceneTouchEvent.getY());
            break;
        }
        case (TouchEvent.ACTION_UP): {
            // when the event is finished, create the path and make the sprite move
            // instead of the history size use the size of your own lists

            Path path = new Path(xCoordinates.size());  
            for (int i = 0; i < xCoordinates.size(); i++) {
                path.to(xCoordinates.get(i), yCoordinates.get(i));  // add the coordinates to the path one by one
            }

            // do the rest and make the sprite move
            PathModifier pathModifier = new PathModifier(2.5f, path);
            pathModifier.setAutoUnregisterWhenFinished(true);
            sprite1.clearEntityModifiers();
            sprite1.registerEntityModifier(pathModifier);
            break;
        }
    }
```

I tested this on my phone (which does not run in debug mode) and it works fine. But to make sure that no Exception will be thrown, you should always test if the xCoordinates list is bigger than 1. Although it is very probable that it is.

Well I hope it helps at least to *go around* your original problem. I noticed that some methods are named differently (e.g. setAutoUnregisterWhenFinished(true);) I guess you are using AndEngine **GLES1** ? I use **GLES2**, so when a method has another name in my code, don't worry and just look for the equivalent in **GLES1** (I didn't rename them because, the code works as it is)

- Christoph

Comment: I almost got that working but only in Debug mode.When in debug mode history size is giving me more than 10 size, but when I run it normally, it just gives me size 1. Any idea whats causing problem.

Comment: Just made an edit to show you my solution, although I couldn't figure out what caused the problem – I hope you can adapt it in your program

Comment: I'm not sure exactly but If I kept break in ACTION_MOVE, history didnt save anything in it.So I always getting either 0 or 1, thus my initial problem. Yes I'm using GLES1! :).